# Fabricjs background with transparent parts

Tags: fabricjs

I have a Fabric.js canvas with a background image that has some transparent parts.  I want the transparent parts to show the color of the div behind the canvas (e.g. red).  So this works:

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor(null);
canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    opacity: 1.0
});
```

Now say I want to to change the opacity of the image to 0.3.  In this case the non-transparent parts of the image show the red underneath.  But I would like the transparent parts to show red, and the non-transparent parts to be faded against a white background.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but you can just load in a .png with transparency in it and it'll show the canvas background in the transparent parts.

For example:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'green';
canvas.renderAll();

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://i.imgur.com/aSEcfuz.png", function(img){
    img.left = 0;
    img.top = 0;
    img.width = 200;
    img.height = 200;
    canvas.add(img);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="fabric" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Workaround which places a white background behind the image and moves it along with the image:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'green';
canvas.renderAll();
var sharedProperties = {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 200,
  height: 200
};
var image;

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: sharedProperties.left,
  top: sharedProperties.top,
  fill: 'white',
  width: sharedProperties.width,
  height: sharedProperties.height
});
canvas.add(rect);

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://i.imgur.com/aSEcfuz.png", function(img) {
  image = img;
  img.left = sharedProperties.left;
  img.top = sharedProperties.top;
  img.width = sharedProperties.width;
  img.height = sharedProperties.height;
  canvas.add(img);
  image.on('moving', function(event) {
    rect.set({
      left: image.left,
      top: image.top
    });
    rect.setCoords();
  });
});
```

```html
<canvas id="fabric" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I am able to show the transparency through as shown in your example.  However, to follow on your snippet, what I would like to do is have the green background, but then bleed a white background through the transparent parts of the red circle so the circle looks red and white instead of red and green.  Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Unless you want to implement this in a hacky way (creating another object with the white background, putting it lower in z-axis then the image and letting it move along with the image), no. Setting a background color is only supported for text elements for now (source: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#backgroundColor)

Comment: Yeah, I think I might have to do some kind of hack like that.

Comment: @Kevin I've edited my answer to add the workaround I was talking about, is this what you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: This is close to my problem.  Imagine though that your circle is solid red, with 100% transparency in the corners of the image . Then you would have a green background and white corners around the circle. I want to make those white corners green as well.  (Note that in this case the problem is only noticeable when the image opacity is less than 1,)  So the fix is to make the white area behind the circle another all-white image that is a cutout in the shape of the non-transparent parts.of the image.  So I'll have to do some image manipulation but I think I can get it to work.